# WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer fastReverse not available

Tags: c#, wmplib

I am writing a small application using WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer. The thing is that the fast reverse method is always not available. I have no problems with fast forward which is working fine. I am playing mp3 files.